# Want to build Bargraph With Delegate and Datasource using protocol

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to build one bar graph view, To create delegate and datasource to that graph view. Creating a protocol for delegate and datasource to the graph.

```
protocol BarGraphDatasource{
    func grapgView(grapgView:BarGraph, numberOfItemsInGraph items:Int)->Int
    func grapgView(grapgView: BarGraph, didSelectItemAtIndex index: Int)
}
```

// Bargraph View class is like below

```
class BarGraph: UIScrollView {


    var  delegte: BarGraphDatasource! = nil{

        didSet{
            self.reloadGraph()
        }
    }

     var barWidth : CGFloat = 24 {

        didSet{
                self.reloadGraph()
        }
    }
    var minimumSpacing : CGFloat = 10 {

        didSet{
            self.reloadGraph()
        }
    }

    var numberOfItems : Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            self.reloadGraph()
        }
    }
     var barColor : UIColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor() {

        didSet{
            self.reloadGraph()
        }
    }



    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.reloadGraph()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
    func reloadGraph(){
        self.setContentSizeForGraph()
    }

    func setContentSizeForGraph() {

        if self.numberOfItems > 0 {
            self.contentSize = CGSizeMake((self.barWidth * CGFloat(self.numberOfItems) + self.minimumSpacing), self.frame.height);
            var xValue:CGFloat = 0
            for i in 1...self.numberOfItems {
                xValue = xValue + CGFloat(CGFloat(i) + self.minimumSpacing)
                print("xValue: \(xValue)")
                let frame = CGRectMake(xValue, 0, self.barWidth, 50)
                let barView = UIView(frame: frame)
                barView.backgroundColor = self.barColor
                self.addSubview(barView)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// This is my ViewController class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,BarGraphDatasource {

    @IBOutlet weak var grapView :  BarGraph?

    var arrayItems: NSArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arrayItems = [1,2,3,4,5]
        grapView?.barWidth = 10;
        grapView?.delegte = self;

        grapView?.reloadGraph()
    }


    func grapgView(grapgView: BarGraph, numberOfItemsInGraph items: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayItems.count // how can i pass this value to the graph view from here       ******* 
    }  
    func grapgView(grapgView: BarGraph, didSelectItemAtIndex index: Int) {
        print(arrayItems[index]) // how can i call this method on click of bar view       ******* 
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

// Here i am unable to get the graph and not calling protocol methods in ViewController class

**numberOfItemsInGraph** when we are setting this i want pass this value to BarGraph in graph

**didSelectItemAtIndex** how to give the action to selected item

Comment: You say, "how can i pass this value to the graph view".  Isn't that what the `return` does?  Since it's a delegate method, I would expect it to be called from the object that references the delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Don't need to call reloadGraph() all the times. When your are assigning delegte it will be called. And you can call it explicitly later.

2nd you have to call these delegate methods from somewhere of the BarGraph Class. I have changed some codes, please try this.

```
    import UIKit

protocol BarGraphDatasource{
    func grapgView(grapgView:BarGraph, numberOfItemsInGraph items:Int)->Int
    func grapgView(grapgView: BarGraph, didSelectItemAtIndex index: Int)
    func grapgView(grapgView: BarGraph, setHeightOfBarAtIndex index: Int)->CGFloat
}
// Bargraph View class is like below

class BarGraph: UIScrollView{


    var  delegte: BarGraphDatasource! = nil{

        didSet{
            self.reloadGraph()
        }
    }

    var barWidth : CGFloat = 24
    var minimumSpacing : CGFloat = 10
    var numberOfItems : Int = 0
    var barColor : UIColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    var barViews : [UIButton] = []


    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.reloadGraph()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
    func reloadGraph(){
        numberOfItems = delegte!.grapgView(self, numberOfItemsInGraph: numberOfItems)
        self.setContentSizeForGraph()

    }

    func setContentSizeForGraph() {

        if self.numberOfItems > 0 {

            self.contentSize = CGSizeMake((self.barWidth * CGFloat(self.numberOfItems) + self.minimumSpacing), self.frame.height);
            var xValue:CGFloat = 0

            for i in 1...self.numberOfItems {
                xValue = xValue + CGFloat(CGFloat(i) + self.minimumSpacing + self.barWidth)
                print("xValue: \(xValue)")
                let frame = CGRectMake(xValue, self.layer.frame.size.height-delegte.grapgView(self, setHeightOfBarAtIndex: i-1), self.barWidth, delegte.grapgView(self, setHeightOfBarAtIndex: i-1))
                let barView = UIButton(frame: frame)
                barView.backgroundColor = self.barColor
                barViews.append(barView)
                barView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BarGraph.send_ButtonIndex(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                self.addSubview(barView)
            }
        }
    }

    func send_ButtonIndex(barView : UIButton)
    {

        delegte!.grapgView(self, didSelectItemAtIndex: barViews.indexOf(barView)!)
    }

}
```

This is the BarGraph Class with datasource. I have implemented one extra delegate method for better use. And Viewcontroller code is following.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,BarGraphDatasource {

    @IBOutlet weak var grapView :  BarGraph?

    var arrayItems: NSArray = []
    var heightOfBars: [CGFloat] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arrayItems = [1,2,3,4,5]
        heightOfBars = [20,30,25,60,40]
        grapView?.barWidth = 20;
        grapView?.barColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        grapView?.minimumSpacing = 15;
        grapView?.delegte = self;
    }


    func grapgView(grapgView: BarGraph, numberOfItemsInGraph items: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayItems.count //pass this value to the graph view from here       *******
    }
    func grapgView(grapgView: BarGraph, didSelectItemAtIndex index: Int) {
        print(arrayItems[index]) //call this method on click of bar view       *******
    }

    func grapgView(grapgView: BarGraph, setHeightOfBarAtIndex index: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return heightOfBars[index]
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: I have used your code in my project, but still i am unable to generate graph. Here is link to my demo app    https://www.dropbox.com/s/0eb8fri3miyqr45/HeaderContainer.zip?dl=0

Comment: @pretam Thank you

Comment: var  delegte: BarGraphDatasource! = nil{

        didSet{
            self.reloadGraph()
        }
    }

Comment: delegate is nil

Comment: You are setting it from ViewController.swift. Then It will not be nill